# Filesystem is corrupt: Corrupt representation Malformed representation header

Tags: git, svn, migration, gitlab, svn2git

want to migrate my projects from svn to gitlab using svn2git.
all projects migrate successfully except one of them.
when I execute svn2git command give me this error: **Filesystem is corrupt: Corrupt representation Malformed representation header**

```
svn2git svn+ssh://src/svn/project --authors /project/authors.txt
W:svn cherry-pick ignored (/branches/WWWWWW:423-593) - missing 2 commit(s) (eg ec2af4046c8d5493126b3335b66416a9737b6d5f)
W:svn cherry-pick ignored (/branches/XXXXXX:2361-2367) - missing 1 commit(s) (eg 00baca7414efa2a6d0d27e83d4b18ef70c444f47)
Found merge parent (svn:mergeinfo prop): 1f6bb8363435bacf84619500152c0bb110fb2e38
Found merge parent (svn:mergeinfo prop): 373627ee985e2a50575122fbc4bdbce53724abaa
Found merge parent (svn:mergeinfo prop): 1b694e29d739e3ecee415de68205bfba7e8407b0
W:svn cherry-pick ignored (/branches/YYYYY:5116-5127) - missing 356 commit(s) (eg 3515ecc473225e5763e934da8ece7072094deb06)
Found merge parent (svn:mergeinfo prop): 91ec0ac4c34acd2bf4a0ca1e8fca45e8929d4f1d
r5132 = 78d1deac2ad93ae64318758e98dd8172bb16a135 (refs/remotes/svn/ZZZZZZ)

Filesystem is corrupt: Corrupt representation '5132 111362 43 152 30744e5af45676756e248545fef2bd20': Malformed representation header at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1806
```

I try to 
1-clean up checkout path, 
2- clean .git, 
3- modify config file,
4-git svn fetch,

any recommendation?

Comment: What does svnadmin `verify PATH-TO-REPOSITORY` say? Do you store your repository on a network share?

Comment: run verify on server and give me same error

Comment: the repository is corrupted. You need to restore a backup. You also need to ensure that you verify your repositories and keep them on a healthy disk.